# python split function not creating a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
x = input('Hey, wanna know the area of a triangle? Enter the height and base  \\n')

for x_element in x.split(" "):
    print(x_element)
```

So the goal is to create a function that calculates the area of a triangle. However when I use the code above and enter two values for the input statement, I'm thinking the split function will separate them into a list but instead, if I enter 5 6 it will create the following output

```
5
6
```

Both numbers are on new lines as opposed to making a list. I'm pretty new to python so I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried `print(x.split(" "))` instead of the for loop?

Comment: You did make a list. Then you iterated over the list with `for`, and printed each element on new line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when x is the string '5 6', then x.split(' ') returns the list [5,6]. Your "for" loop is iterating over that list and printing each item in the list.  By default, the print() function adds a newline after the arguments.

Comment: I see that makes sense, I didnt realize the for loop was causing that. Thank you for explaining

Answer (score 0):

You are printing each value in the list individually. By default, `print` inserts a trailing newline, so they appear on separate lines.

If you want to print the list, just do so.

```
x = input('Hey, wanna know the area of a triangle? Enter the height and base  \\n')

print(x.split(' '))
```